# Retrieving values from a php service in HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, api

I am trying to build a website that displays a google map with a user location (lat/long) from a php service that I wrote.

I already have a php script that gets the lat/long from a mobile app (via POST from the client), stores it in a DB, and read it back from the DB into two variables, let's call them $lat and $long. To make sure I have the right values in $lat and $long, I did a simple echo and got the two values.

I am struggling with understanding how to read these values from my index.html script. All the examples that I have seen suggest keeping the php code in the html file but I would rather keep them separate. I am also not sure how to assign these values to parameters in HTML/Javacript so I can actually display them on the map.

So my questions are: 1. how do I call that php file from HTML? 2. and how do I read $lat and $long from the php service and assign them to parameters in HTML/Javascript that I can display on the map?

EDIT: here is my PHP code and my index.html (Which is a 1:1 copy from the Google Maps v3 docs).

location.php:

```
$content = file_get_contents('php://input');
$post_data = json_decode($content , true);
$lat = $post_data['lat'];
$long = $post_data['long'];

//CONNECT TO MYSQL
$con1 = mysql_connect("localhost", "xxxxx", "yyyy", "zzzzz");
if ($con1->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
   } 
    if (!$db_selected) {
        die ('Can\'t use foo : ' . mysql_error());
    }

    if (!empty($lat)) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO LocationInfo (latitude, longitude) 

                              VALUES ('$lat', '$long');";
    mysql_query($sql) or die ('Error updating database: ' . mysql_error());
 }

$read_query = "SELECT * FROM LocationInfo;";
$results = mysql_query($read_query) or die ('Error reading from database: ' . mysql_error());
$column = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)){
    $column[] = $row;
}


$current_lat = $column[sizeof($column) - 1]['latitude'];
$current_long = $column[sizeof($column) - 1]['longitude'];

echo $current_lat;
echo $current_long;

?>
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My GeoLocation</title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true"></script>
    <script>

var map;

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 14
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  if(navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
                                       position.coords.longitude);

      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        map: map,
        position: pos,
        content: 'Location found using HTML5.'
      });
```

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: Don't worry, I am still just testing it on my local machine. thanks though :)

Comment: when you get done are you going to retest using mysqli or pdo ? no one was assuming you would attack localhost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to get those variables in Javascript is to output them from PHP to JS, there is no direct bridge, so you will need in the HTML output a script block with the values you got from your SQL query, it will be something like this:

```
<script>
  var lat = <?php echo $lat ?>;
  var long = <?php echo $long ?>;
</script>
```

Now you can use this variables in your javascripts to invoke the map, as a note you can add the variables definition to your main JS block as well.

EDIT:
Rename index.html to index.php

```
<?php include_once('location.php') ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My GeoLocation</title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true"></script>
    <script>

var map;

function initialize() {
 // var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $lat ?>,<?php echo $long ?>);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 14
    //mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    //center: myLatlng
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  if(navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
                                       position.coords.longitude);

      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        map: map,
        position: pos,
        content: 'Location found using HTML5.'
      });
```

Comment: Where do I reference the PHP file though?

Comment: The HTML needs to be in the PHP file, there is a way to have 1 php file with the HTML, and another one with the logic, and only output the values, let me update my answer

Comment: Thanks Ramy but this is not working. I combined the files like you suggested and it continues to work both as a web server and to display my site, but when I plug in the variables like you showed nothing happens. Any other thoughts? How can I debug this / print these variables to make sure I can even access them?